# i want to delete one specific user from all these three table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

[![ i have three tables see image.i want to delete one specific user from all three tables at one time .how can i do that? please help me

am trying in this way

`PropertyComEntities db = new PropertyComEntities();
            User userObj = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.userID == ID);
            expert expObj = db.experts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.userID == id);
            db.Users.Remove(userObj);
            db.experts.Remove(expObj);
            db.SaveChanges();`]

Comment: This is where foreign keys come in extremely handy. Just saying.

Comment: RhapX can u exolain with a query please

Comment: if you were utilizing foreign keys, you wouldn't need multiple queries. You would simply delete the data from one table, using 1 query, and the rest of the tables would delete related data for that user. There's no query, just making a statement. Perhaps look into foreign keys for later development.

Comment: got it RhapX . thank u